# datetimepicker() on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to do some dynamic action with `datetimepicker()` i.e when changes occurs in date, month or year suddenly it should trigger datetimepicker.

```js
$('#cmd').click(function() {
  $('#content').append('<br>a datepicker <input class="datepicker_recurring_start"/>');
});
$('body').on('focus', ".datepicker_recurring_start", function() {
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="content">
  <input class="datepicker_recurring_start" />
</div>
<button id="cmd">add a datepicker</button>
```

In the above link, they were using datepicker(), it is cool and working fine.I want to do the same action with datetimepicker() can anyone help me.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/98/)

Comment: why not just include the datetimepicker and try

Comment: @ArunPJohny datetimepicker() is not working like datepicker()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kL0pspof/1/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for your effort but this not what i'm expecting.Actually i am getting this result.I need to see the changes.While using datepicker() when i change date i can see the changes in calender instantly likewise i want to do it in datetimepicker().Please check the difference in datepicker() and datetimepicker().